# Count values shared between groups

Tags: r, count, aggregate, shared

Here is some dummy data:

```
class<-c("ab","ab","ad","ab","ab","ad","ab","ab","ad","ab","ad","ab","av")
otu<-c("ab","ac","ad","ab","ac","ad","ab","ac","ad","ab","ad","ac","av")
value<-c(0,1,12,13,300,1,2,3,4,0,0,2,4)
type<-c("b","c","d","a","b","c","d","d","d","c","b","a","a")
location<-c("b","c","d","a","b","d","d","d","d","c","b","a","a")
datafr1<-data.frame(class,otu,value,type,location)
```

I want to get rid of any OTU if any replicate within the group 'location' and 'type' is 0, because I am interested in OTUs shared between all the replicates within a group.

I want to calculate two things. 
One: percent abundance of 'value' for all OTUs shared between the group 'location' and type' (abundance) 
Two: count the number of OTUs shared in each class (otu.freq)

Caveat is that I would like the OTUs to classified by 'class', and not the OTU name (because it s meaningless).

Expected output:

```
   class location type  abundance  otu.freq
    ab        a    a      79        2
    av        a    a      21        1
    ab        b    b     100        1
    ab        c    c     100        1
    ad        d    c     100        1
    ab        d    d      24        2         
    ad        d    d      76        2
```

I have a much larger data frame and have tried the suggestions using dplyr [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28742825/count-occurence-of-values-for-every-possible-pair) but I ran out of RAM, so I don't know if it worked or not.

The solution provided by @Akron below does not count the occurrences where the abundance is 0, but it does not get rid of that OTU from the other replicates within that group. If any OTU has an abundance of 0, then it is not shared between that group and I need to completely discount it from the abundance and otu.freq calculation.

```
library(dplyr)    
so_many_shared3<-datafr1 %>% 
      group_by(class, location, type) %>% 
      summarise(abundance=sum(value)/sum(datafr1[['value']])*100, otu.freq=sum(value !=0))


   class location type  abundance  otu.freq
1    ab        a    a  4.3859649     2
2    ab        b    b 87.7192982     1
3    ab        c    c  0.2923977     1
4    ab        d    d  1.4619883     2
5    ad        b    b  0.0000000     0
6    ad        d    c  0.2923977     1
7    ad        d    d  4.6783626     2
8    av        a    a  1.1695906     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in one step using either `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
val = sum(datafr1$value)
setDT(datafr1)[order(class,type), list(abundance = 
               sum(value)/val*100, otu.freq = .N), 
               by = .(class, location, type)]
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
datafr1 %>% 
     group_by(class, location, type) %>% 
     summarise(abundance=sum(value)/sum(datafr1[['value']])*100, otu.freq=n())
 #   class location type  abundance otu.freq
 #1    ab        a    a  4.3859649        2
 #2    ab        b    b 87.7192982        2
 #3    ab        c    c  0.2923977        2
 #4    ab        d    d  1.4619883        2
 #5    ad        b    b  0.0000000        1
 #6    ad        d    c  0.2923977        1
 #7    ad        d    d  4.6783626        2
 #8    av        a    a  1.1695906        1
```

#### Update

Based on the new criteria, I am updating the code suggested by the OP (@K.Brannen)

```
  datafr1 %>%
       group_by(class, location, type) %>% 
       summarise(abundance=sum(value)/sum(datafr1[['value']])*100, 
             otu.freq=sum(value !=0))
```

#### Update2

Based on the updated expected result

```
  datafr1 %>%
       filter(value!=0) %>% 
       group_by(location, type) %>% 
       mutate(value1=sum(value)) %>% 
       group_by(class, add=TRUE) %>% 
       summarise(abundance=round(100*sum(value)/unique(value1)), 
                         otu.freq=n())
  #    location type class abundance otu.freq
  #1        a    a    ab        79        2
  #2        a    a    av        21        1
  #3        b    b    ab       100        1
  #4        c    c    ab       100        1
  #5        d    c    ad       100        1
  #6        d    d    ab        24        2
  #7        d    d    ad        76        2
```

Comment: These both give an output, but the dplyr version is quicker. However, there are some Classes that have an abundance of 0 and an otu.freq that is not 0 (also shown in your dplyr output). I want to count the number of OTUs that are shared, and a value of 0 means that the OTU is not shared between the groups.

Comment: so_many_shared<-so_many_melt %>% 
  group_by(Class, location, type) %>% 
  summarise(abundance=sum(value)/sum(so_many_melt[['value']])*100, otu.freq=sum(value !=0))        Does this do it? I want to make sure it is doing what I think it is.

Comment: @K.Brannen I was away.  I will check your update soon.

Comment: @K.Brannen But your code gives the `7th` row otu.freq as `2` instead of the expected `1`.  Is there any typo in the expected?

Comment: Ok, so I have figured out something else that is problematic. If the OTU has a value of 0 across any of the replicates of location and type, it is not shared between all those samples. Is there any way to get rid of OTUs that have a 0 in any replicates, and not count that OTU for the abundance or otu.freq?

Comment: @K.Brannen Did you mean if any `0` is present in the group combinations, that freq should be 0?

Comment: @K.Brannen Can you update your dataset reflecting those changes and the expected result (makes a good reference point)

Comment: I changed the question a bit as well as added some of your suggestions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72273/discussion-between-k-brannen-and-akrun).

Comment: @K.Brannen I didn't see the new expected output in your edit.

Comment: it's better labeled in there now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a mistake in your aggregate function. If you want to count the frequency of otu, you should put otu before the "~" sign. After that, you can just merge them using the `join` function in the `plyr` library

```
abund_shared_freq<-aggregate(otu~class+location+type,datafr1,length)
library(plyr)
join(abund_shared, abund_shared_freq, by=c("class", "location","type"), type="left")
```

Output:

```
  class location type  abundance otu
1    ab        a    a  4.3859649   2
2    ab        b    b 87.7192982   2
3    ab        c    c  0.2923977   2
4    ab        d    d  1.4619883   2
5    ad        b    b  0.0000000   1
6    ad        d    c  0.2923977   1
7    ad        d    d  4.6783626   2
8    av        a    a  1.1695906   1
```